# Is it enough to call glActiveTexture to edit a texture once it has already been bound?

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

If my understanding is correct, a texture unit has a number of targets (`GL_TEXTURE_2D` etc.) that I can bind textures to. I can change the currently active texture unit with `glActiveTexture`. When I'm calling `glBindTexture`, I bind the specified texture object to the specified target of the currently active texture unit, right?

When I want to later change the parameters of a texture or call a function like `glTexSubImage2D`, is it enough to call glActiveTexture with the texture unit that my texture is bound to? Or do I have to call `glBindTexture` everytime, even if the texture is already bound to a unit?

Answer (score 2):

So long as you know what state is bound to which unit, you can rely on just changing `glActiveTexture` to switch to the right unit to find it.

However, you should not rely upon this for this purpose. Not because OpenGL is unreliable, but because you may be *wrong* about what you think you've bound to which unit.

Furthermore, it blurs the line between binding a texture to render with it and binding a texture to *modify* it. You want the two to be entirely separate. First, because modifying a texture's state in the rendering loop (where you're binding it to modify it) is bad form and likely to be slow. And second, so that when it comes time to adopt GL 4.5 and DSA, you can do so quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Texture unit as pipes present on GPU . 
There are many such texture units present on GPU. By calling glActivateTexture() you are telling OpenGL driver to tell GPU that which ever texture I will bind next load/connect it in mentioned texture unit.By saying glBindTexture() you are telling driver that whatever operations I am about to do, please do it on the texture I have bound. As once you have call glTextureImage2D your texture is residing in driver memory and hence you dont have direct access to it. So driver has given you handle to texture object which you bind and tell driver which resource I am talking about.

So when ever you render its always good to do both activate texture unit and then bind your texture. As you have done activate first and bind later the texture will be automatically bound to unit you have given.

If you dont mention texture unit by default GL_TEXTURE0 will be used and hence sometimes it could be confusing.

Hope this helps.